# Dynamics of fluid

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

While reading on Wikipedia about the partial differential equations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation), 
I wondered how dynamics for the ﬂuid occur in an infinite-dimensional conﬁguration space? Can somebody help me by providing an example.

Comment: A Mathematician (M) and an Engineer (E) attend a lecture by a
Physicist. The topic concerns physics in spaces with dimensions of 9 and even higher.  The M is sitting, enjoying the lecture, while the E
is frowning and looking generally confused and puzzled.  By the end
the E has a terrible headache.  At the end, the M comments about the
wonderful lecture.  The E says "How do you understand this stuff?"
M: "I just visualize the process."
E: "How can you POSSIBLY visualize something that occurs in
9-dimensional space?"
M: "Easy, first visualize it in N-dimensional space, then let N go to 9."

Comment: @Pockets  the dynamics of a particle can be described by maximum 3 numbers, if you add time component  then it can be four numbers, but I wondered how infinity numbers?

Comment: Picture a particle which exists in $n$ dimensions. Let $n$ go to $\infty$.

Comment: @Pockets, mathematically it's fine but want to understand it physical point of view.

Comment: The problem is that there is none. At a research-theoretic level, we've done extensive work on the implications and results of the existence of higher dimensions, [but at the end of the day, we really don't have any physical analogue for them](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/146483).

Comment: But Wikipedia says "The dynamics for the rigid body take place in a finite-dimensional configuration space; the dynamics for the ﬂuid occur in an infinite-dimensional conﬁguration space."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38487/discussion-between-real-hilbert-and-pockets).

Comment: These are *theoretical* models of physics. If you have further questions, please head over to physics.SE - they'll be able to offer you much more help than we here.

Comment: There are a finite, albeit extremely large, number of molecules making up a moving fluid.  It is intractable to apply Newtonian mechanics to solve for the aggregate motion of these molecules.  Instead the Navier-Stokes equations governing fluid motion at the macroscopic level are derived under a continuum approximation -- whereby the fluid is assumed to composed of individual fluid particles that are dense in space. The velocity field we solve for is really a local volume average of the discrete molecular velocities.

Comment: The local volume average is taken over a length scale that is large relative to the mean free path of the molecules. If you are faced with a flow problem where the physical length scale (say the radius of a pipe) are large relative to the molecular mean free path, then this approximation works well.